# Variable widget for admin-inline fields

Tags: django, model, widget, inline, admin

Let's consider the following model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
   pass

class TagType(models.Model):
   tag_name = models.CharField()
   tag_value_type = models.CharField() #or any other serializable field

#and a class, which is ManyToMany for Item x TagType
class Tag(models.Model):
   item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
   tag_type = models.ForeignKey(TagType)
   value = models.CharField()
```

In django admin, I would like to have inline edit for Tags inside Item admin. However,
I would like to have variable controls for value field of Tag class. For instance, let's
consider that I have two tag types: COLOUR, which would have a select/option widget, 
and a SIZE tag, which would have an DecimalField widget.

How can I change the widget for value field upon a change of tag_type field value? Is this
even possible? Is this hard to achieve? This means, that there could possibly be different widgets for value fields of Tag instancef within one Item instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the widget for the form class used by the inline model, where you can check the tag_type, and then tell the value field which widget you want to use for value.

However, this is going to be problematic for creating new Tag records...

When you're editing existing records, you'll have a value for tag_type to determine the widget to use, but new records won't yet have a value - which widget would you show?

I think your best best is to have a two-step process. One that creates the TagType, and one that creates/edits the Tag(s).